# Using Selenium+Python, I am finding an element with the find element command, but the element is dynamic, how can I prevent it throwing an exception?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver-python

So I am using find_element to define a variable like so

```
 WinCondition = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='bonus-game-state back bonus-game-end red']")
```

However the element is dynamic, this is intentional, but when the code does not find the element, it throws an exception and ends the whole process, I simply want it to do nothing if it does not find the element, because sometimes the element is on the page, sometimes it isn't

I only want it to do something if it finds the element, and nothing if it doesn't. Makes sense?

How can I prevent it from throwing the exception?

Comment: try: except: Is what you'll be looking for.

Answer (score 0):

check if an element exists then do something otherwise skip it.

```
try:    
    if winCondition.exists():
      do somthing
    else:
       skip it.
except:
    print("element not exists")
```